# Auto filling a field in access 2003 with data from another table

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, hyperlink

I have an access 2003 database with many tables. Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve. I have a table and form for my candidates. On this table is a field for name and a field for an enrolment number. Is it possible for my other form to fill in the enrolment number on that form automatically when the same name is selected. For example, if I have a candidate on my candidates table with an enrolment number filled in. If I select that candidate on my other form how can I make it automatically fill in the enrolment number. Hope this is clear enough.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

If you are using a combo box to select the candidate from the candidates table, the enrollment number can be one of the columns, in which case you can simply refer to the column in the controlsource of a textbox:

```
 =MyCombo.Column(2)
```

Similarly, you can use DLookUp, but it can be comparatively slow if your tables are large:

```
 =DlookUp("enrollmentnumber","candidates","UniqueNumericID=" UniqueNumericID)
```

Where UniqueNumericID is a control or field (column) in the form or the form's recordset.

It may also be possible to create a query that holds all the relevant data and use that for your form's recordsource. This is quite a nice solution, usually, for example:

```
SELECT This, That, Candidates.EnrollmentNumber 
FROM ExamsJunctionTable 
INNER JOIN Candidates 
ON ExamsJunctionTable.CandidateID = Candidates.UniqueCandidateID
```

For this to work properly you need to ensure that you database is well set-up and that the queries that need to be updatable are updatable.